# Reference variable in one event handler, in another event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following event handlers chained.
The code is used for detecting if user has scrolled, but thats not important. More a question on scope.

```
this.myElement.on('touchstart', (e) => {
    const startY = window.pageYOffset;
  }).on('touchend', (e) => {
    const endY = window.pageYOffset;
    if (startY === endY) {
      //do stuff
    }
  })
```

How can i reference startY variable defined in first event handler (touchstart), in touchend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to move it outside the handler (into a higher scope).

```
let startY;

this.myElement.on('touchstart', (e) => {
    startY = window.pageYOffset;
}).on('touchend', (e) => {
    const endY = window.pageYOffset;
    if (startY === endY) {
      //do stuff
    }
});
```